# Window open and close effect with c# in windows application

Tags: c#

please give me idea about effect. in android or windows vista a effect is used when any application window is open or closed. effect is like grow and shrink. very similar like jquery transfer effect. i can generate that effect like window size increment or decrement with in time but it flicker and not smooth like professional. so please guide how to generate that effect in windows application which look very professional. also tell me is there any free open source library to generate that kind of effect. please me with sample code.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you use winforms or WPF? Setting alpha or size with a timer in wpf will give you ugly flickering results.
you have to define an animation and apply it to your window.
For a short introduction on animations read this:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/IntroductionToWPFAnimations.aspx

If you want to animate the whole window you should read another article:

pavanpodila.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9C9E888164859398!634.entry

It deals with some problems that can occur if you want  to animate windows propertys.

Comment: To bad. I never used animations in winforms. It has to be animated i always use Blend and WPF